# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, server-error

I've been working on this web application for a couple of weeks now.  <-- Key information! And everything has been working fine; data goes into the database, etc.

It's an ASP.Net 4.0 / C# Web Form.

Today, I added a new Web Form page and added a GridView to it.  It worked fine.

I was editing the columns of the GridView, making some wider for long strings like addresses.   It all worked fine. Fine.

I wanted to make the "Comments" field wider and multi-line so it displayed nice in the GridView, so I converted it to a "Template Field" and set the Item Control width.  When I refreshed the page I got this error:

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Source File: E:\inetpub\StartupNow\web.config    Line: 9

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5491

-- I get that error on both pages.  Even the one I was not working on and worked fine.

Comment: Just curious, when you make these changes, are you compiling and deploying the application?  Or are you editing the site directly?

Comment: Does the file show up in your reference folder?
If so what does it point to?

Comment: I'm editing the site directly, like I've been doing to all the sites I work on for the last 8 or 9 years.  I did find the issue.  The Application Pool assigned to this site was set for Framework 2.xxxx instead of 4.0.  I changed it to 4.0 and that resolved the problem.  I know, I probably should not be working on the changes directly, sometimes in notepad, but I've had issues trying to work any other way.  Lack of training is my biggest issue.  ;-)

Comment: DaniDev, that's deeper than I have experience with.  I don't know what file to look for or ... over my head.  Sorry.  I've no training, I just make simple web forms.   (I have resolved the problem, though.  Application Pool was set to the wrong Framework version.)

Comment: Glad you were able to sort it out. As far as training, I think you are learning as you go, just as the rest of us. keep asking questions.
BTW, what are you using as a development platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Application Pool for the web site was set to Framework 2.xxx.  When I added a Template Field to the GridView, that must have required Framework 4.xxx which is the framework I'm developing the site in.
When I set the Application Pool in IIS 7.0 to Framework 4.0 that resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured.

Comment: Could a virtual directory all of a sudden become "not configured" after two weeks of working fine?

Comment: @DavidMegnin - Once upon a time i screwed up a production application by messing with the permissions on the file system. I decided to share out the application root directory, and it caused IIS Authentication to get mad.  Did permissions on the server alter in any way?

Comment: Yeah, I could see how that might happen.  I looked on the server and found that the Application Pool was set to Framework 2.xxxx, so I changed it to 4.0 and that fixed it.  Yay!

Answer (score 1):

Install .Net 3.5 on machine that's hosting the app.